# JQuery events get unbound when I delete and re-add them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a custom view with sorting capabilities and has something that almost works, except that once it sorts once the click events to the elements being sorted become unbound, likely as a result of how i remove the elements and re add them sorted.

Is there a better way to do this such that the 'children' keep the bound events?

```
function sortcontainer(container, sortby)
{
 alert(container.data("sessionlist").datetimesort);
 var children = container.children();

 children.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (sortby == "datetime")
  {
   if (!$(a).attr("starttime"))
    return -1;
   else if (!$(b).attr("starttime"))
    return 1;
   else if (container.data("sessionlist").datetimesort)
    return $(a).attr("starttime") - $(b).attr("starttime");
   else
    return $(b).attr("starttime") - $(a).attr("starttime");

  }
 }); // End sort function

 container.empty();
 container.html(children);

 if (sortby == "datetime")
  container.data('sessionlist').datetimesort = !container.data('sessionlist').datetimesort;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then you will want to define you click events using the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) syntax. What live does is bind the event for all current and future events matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're binding directly to the elements in *container*.  Instead, I would use the *delegate* method (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the events once to the *container* element.  That way, the event will not be affected by moving or adding/removing of elements that are children of *container*.